# Characters and finite group representations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I just saw the proof of the theorem where 2 representations of a finite group $G$ with the same characters are isomorphic\equivalent representations. The proof uses the orthogonality relations of characters for irreducible characters, and immediately deduce the fact that if we have all the irreducible characters in both reps the exact number of times, then we have equivalence of the representations. I could not see why this proof is sufficient. Could anybody elaborate more about it? I would expect the proof to give explicitly the map which we use to show that the representations are equivalent. But I could not see such proof anywhere in the literature. What am I missing in this proof?

Comment: That you can prove two objects isomorphic without having to write down the isomorphism?

Comment: Maschke's theorem implies that if two reps have the same irreducible components, all with equal multiplicities, then they are isomorphic. Oh, you do need also the bit that two irreducible reps are isomorphic iff they have the same character.

Comment: This already happens for finite sets: two finite sets are isomorphic iff they have the same cardinality, and you can often compute that two finite sets have the same cardinality without being able to write down an isomorphism between them.